# What is the best way to override text string in Magento module's Save.php?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I just need to change one string which is hardcoded (this was surprise for me) in

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Save.php` ,

in `execute()` method:

```
 $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the product attribute.'));
```

I must change `'You saved the product attribute.'` to another text with plugins/rewrites. As far as I know, the plugin can change only arguments' values or return value. If I will use extending the class, I can just overwrite the method, but then I have to copy-paste all the method's code.

Is there a better way to change this one string?

Comment: You want to change the only message `You saved the product attribute`?

Comment: @KeyurShah Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To translate the text you can use [translation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html) feature of `Magento2`. If you are using custom theme then you just need to create `en_US.csv` (I am assuming you have this locale If you have different then you can create different csv i.e for German(de_DE.csv)).

`app\design\adminhtml\YOUR_THEME_VENDOR\YOUR_THEMEN_NAME\Magento_Catalog\i18n\en_US.csv`

In this CSV file, you need to write like this,

`"You saved the product attribute.","Your custom message here"`

Then just execute

`php bin/magento s:s:d` and clear your cache `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: Thank you. I understand that translations are the best way to change string. But accroding to my test task I need to do this with plugins or rewrites. Do you mean that this methods a-priory are terrible/overkill for such purposes?

Comment: It's always best practice to use `translation` feature to just change the text. `plugins/rewrites` is used when you need to change logic at code level or you need to add some new feature :) @Audiophile

Comment: This doesn't work... The string remains the same.

Comment: You're wrong, the i18n folder must be put in the module's folder, not theme's

Comment: No, you can also put in your module folder :) Please try it It works @Audiophile

Comment: Please let me know your csv file directory @Audiophile

Comment: app\design\frontend\Asoft\TestTheme\Magento_Catalog\i18n\en_US.csv - doesn't work. app\code\Asoft\TestModule\i18n\en_US.csv - works

Comment: After putting the CSV file , did you execute `php bin/magento s:s:d` ? (I mean static-content:deploy) @Audiophile

Comment: After puting translation to theme - yes (and I flushed cache also). After puting to module's dir I just flushed the cache.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that you need translation for `adminhtml` and I suggested you for `frontend` theme that's why it is not working. (For this you just need to put into the `adminhtml` directory). Anyway you found the answer so cool :) @Audiophile